# Python не видит папку

Tags: python-3.x

При попытке перенести файл в папку Python выдаёт ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\file_manag.py", line 29, in <module>
    os.replace(path + g, end_path + g)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 
'C:/Users/Admin/Documentsdesktop.ini' -> 'C:/Users/Admin/Documentsdesktop.ini'
```

Вот сам код:

```
import os

path = "C:/Users/Admin/Documents"
end_path = "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/test"

files = os.listdir(path)

if os.listdir(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if (file.endswith(".txt")):
                for g in files:
                    os.replace(path + g, end_path + g)
else:
    pass
```

Помогите исправить.

Comment: `path +'/' +  g`  или `os.path.join(path, g)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конце пути в переменных path,end_path нет разделителя каталогов. `+` в этом случае склеивает название каталога и файла. Правильно:

```
path = os.path.join("C:","Users","Admin","Documents")
end_path = os.path.join("C:","Users","Admin","Documents","test")

os.replace(os.path.join(path , g), os.path.join(end_path , g))
```

или например с pathlib очень удобно прицеплять элементы через деление

```
path = pathlib.Path("C:/Users/Admin/Documents")
end_path = pathlib.Path("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/test")
...
           os.replace(path / g, end_path / g)
```

Comment: os.replace(path / g, end_path / g)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
выходит ошибка

Comment: os.replace(os.path.join(path, g), os.path.join(end_path, g))

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'C:/Users/Admin/Documents\\desktop.ini' -> 'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/test\\desktop.ini'

это при первом случае

Comment: `path / g` - обрати внимание что переменные завернуты в pathlib

Comment: `s/test\\d` ох уж эта винда... сейчас поправлю ответ